# Creative uses for version control

Tags: version-control

I'm searching for creative -- or at least non-standard -- uses for [Version Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). I have a specific purpose in mind, but I don't want to stifle your creative thoughts with any sort of limitations.

To that end, don't eliminate a creative use of VCS dealing with source code just because I said creative/non-standard: That doesn't mean it can't deal with source. It just means I'm looking for ideas other than branching, merging, tagging, rollback, and forking.

**For example:** I would consider the use of Version Control as a quick & dirty [SharePoint](http://www.microsoft.com/sharepoint/) knock-off as a passable answer, but just barely.

What other interesting uses have you seen?

Comment: At the very least, this question should be Community Wiki, but even then I'd still vote to close it.

Comment: Made it community-wiki, meant to do that originally but overlooked it.

Comment: Not sure why you think it deserves to be closed... I see it as programming related, and now that it's community wiki, I'm obviously not looking for a rep-boost. Care to explain?

Comment: @Adam Tuttle: You're specifically asking how to use software that is designed to help programmers do their job in situations for which it was not designed. That's not programming related by definition.

Comment: I disagree. Is a question regarding using Eclipse for something other than writing programs not programming-related? Who knows Version Control Systems better -- who can better answer my question -- than people who use it every day? Who is more likely to have a creative use of VCS for photography: a Photographer who happens to also be a developer well versed in VCS, or one who isn't? Therefore, I would argue there is no better place to ask this question. It's directly targeted at people who use programming-related software.

Comment: Just because knowledge is likely for programmers to have doesn't make that knowledge programming related. I do not believe this is a question that belongs on SO. Luckily SO is a democracy and open debate like this helps other would-be closers decide for themselves whether to vote to close it or not.

Answer (score 6):

I have used SVN for managing my photos.  It is much better than having a bunch of 'saved as' copies.  Plus my technically inclined family members can get the latest pictures from the TRUNK branch...works out quite well.

Comment: I can see that being useful if you're putting together different photo albums - tag instead of copy. Interesting. Thanks for the idea. :)

Comment: I have been thinking about the same thing. Care about sharing some details on the setup?

Comment: Fredrik, it is just a simple set up.  Basically I have all my pictures set up by Genre; Family, Friends, Baby, etc.  I often do many versions of the same photo like black&white or cropping.  I like the ability to grab the original, make modifications, check back in.  Then I will notify those that might be interested, they log in and grab latest.  This also allows me to only ever have one version on my local (save space) and keep all the revisions on my server which is backed up nightly.

Answer (score 5):

A personal diary, or for [writers/novelists](http://www.ryumaou.com/hoffman/netgeek/2008/07/version-control-for-writers/).

Answer (score 3):

See the [Using Git For What It Is Not Intended](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/110411) [sic] contest.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've seen it used as an alternative for an FTP Warez Share in one place I worked.

```
Developer: "Hi, can you open port 22 for FTP"
SysAdmin: "Nope Company policy"
Developer: "Ok Fair enough"
```

Several days later I saw a couple of episodes of Family guy + some other random stuff appear in the SVN Repo under a folder called "File Drop" in the form of several split .rar files

Uncannily they were checked in not by a named user but by the sys account we used for downloading the repo during builds... that account was subsequently locked to ReadOnly

Comment: Inappropriate at work, but creative!

Answer (score 2):

I use SVN for hosting photos.

But not albums, just pictures I post to forums, send via IM, etc.

In this way I may always fix a picture later, from color adjustments to replacing with 10 000 x 10 000 blinking GIF to blow the mentioned forum apart (never done this, but...)

Answer (score 2):

I've used version control (darcs) for a local wiki on the filesystem. Because darcs repos are fetched over http, making my local repository available from my web server meant anyone could grab a copy of my wiki, and make their own changes.

To get new changes, I would fetch from their repository.

One benefit of this is that there's no spam, because you can just rollback changes and stop fetching from anyone who entered spam.

I kept a script to fetch from remote repositories in the repository itself, so there's no central server to roll over and die, and it's easy to find other wikizens when you're grabbing a new wiki.

The wiki system I wrote never saw much use, but [gitit](http://github.com/jgm/gitit/network) is an active project with the same idea (darcs or git), and more features.

I also use version control for many of the files in my home directory: .zshrc .emacs and many more.

Answer (score 1):

I could imagine to use it for all of my file system. I think it is also very useful for word documents, E-Mail data bases from the favorite mail program, images (as mentioned above), desktop symbols.
You could benefit in many ways!

Answer (score 1):

Checking in your toolchain can make provisioning developers boxes a metter of one simple install and a pull.

Answer (score 1):

[Flashbake](http://bitbucketlabs.net/flashbake/) Offers source controll for ordinary people, [Boing boing have advertised it as being useful for writers](http://www.boingboing.net/2009/02/13/flashbake-free-versi.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit tricky at times (because of root access), but I've used svn for hosting my machine setup.

```
/etc/X11/xorg.conf
/etc/apt/sources.list
/home/me/.*
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

I remember reading about some guy who used it to keep his virtual machines synced between home and office. So check in when leaving the office and check out when get home.

Comment: I suppose that kind of makes sense, but the VM disk images would be huge -- it would take a long time to transmit all that data.